# Javascript events on top-of-window enter and leave?

Tags: javascript, window, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm seeking a mouse event to detect when the mouse enter the top of the window, and leaves the top of the window. I don't mean the top of the webpage, but the top of the window.

There's no pre-existing "element" on the page i'm trying to attach the event to, but i think programmatically adding an invisible, fixed html element to the top of the page might be ok.

I like the clientY method with onmousemove, but that will fire repeatedly, which i don't want-- only want firing on enter and leave. Don't want my code to have to handle multiple firings.

This should work with ANY webpage-- i do not have any control over the HTML on the page (except for elements i add to the page programmatically).

Need only support modern browsers, simplest method possible, no jquery.

This method works great! But it prevents clicking elements behind it, which is not ok.

```
(function (){        
var oBanana = document.createElement("div"); 
oBanana.style.position = "fixed"
oBanana.style.top = "0"
oBanana.style.left = "0"
oBanana.style.height= "100px"
oBanana.style.width = "100%"
oBanana.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {alert('in');});
oBanana.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {alert('out');});
document.body.appendChild(oBanana);
})();
```

Next i tried this, which inserts a small hotzone at the top of the page. I realized that, due to my scenario, i DON'T want mouse-out on the hotzone-- rather i want mouseover on everything BELOW the hotzone. Here's my first attempt at that, but fails because the hotzone gets the body event, plus the body event fires repeatedly:

```
(function (){        
var oHotzone = document.createElement("div"); 
oHotzone.id = "fullscreen-hotzone"
oHotzone.style.position = "fixed"
oHotzone.style.top = "0"
oHotzone.style.left = "0"
oHotzone.style.height= "10px"
oHotzone.style.width = "100%"
oHotzone.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {alert('hotzone');});
document.body.appendChild(oHotzone);
document.body.style.marginTop = "10px"
document.body.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {alert('body');});
})();
```

Appreciate any help!
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

It's the simplest you can do with vanilla javascript.

Function:

```
 // create a one-time event
function onetime(node, type, callback) {

    // create event
    node.addEventListener(type, function(e) {
        // remove event
        e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
        // call handler
        return callback(e);
    });
}
```

Implementation:

```
 // one-time event
onetime(document.getElementById("hiddenTopElement"), "mouseenter", handler);
onetime(document.getElementById("hiddenTopElement"), "mouseleave" , hanlder);

// handler function
function handler(e) {
    alert("You'll only see this once!");
}
```

Comment: plz help a beginner understand how to set this up for both mouse enter and leave events. thx for reply!

Comment: I added two lines  in the implementation:
onetime(document.getElementById("hiddenTopElement"), "mouseenter", handler);
onetime(document.getElementById("hiddenTopElement"), "mouseleave" , hanlder);

Comment: great! i set it up here: ok, i set this up here: https://jsfiddle.net/wq0maj79/1/
but i want it to fire every time, not just once. (When i said i don't want multiple firings, i was talking about how mousemove fires everytime you move the mouse, even if you're still hovering over the same element). Oh i see, i can just remove the removeEventListener

Comment: getting closer: https://jsfiddle.net/wq0maj79/4/

now need to add element to page on page load...

Comment: i made a much simpler version of yours, that works. Why is yours better? https://jsfiddle.net/vycc7zro/4/

Comment: Because, as far as I understood rom your request, you don't want the event to fire all the time.

I thought it'd be too easy if you wanted something as simple as this.

Comment: no, i mean i can get the firing behavior i want with yours just by removing the removeEventListener line. But plz see my version, it's simpler in other ways.

Comment: plz see almost-solution added to my OP. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

my OP could have probably been stated better, but i'm happy with this solution. The fixed div blocked hover events on the body below, so the body hover event does not happen until the mouse leaves the hotzone. Perfect.

```
// create hotzone and add event
var oHotzone = document.createElement("div"); 
oHotzone.id = "fullscreen-hotzone"
oHotzone.style.position = "fixed"
oHotzone.style.top = "0"
oHotzone.style.left = "0"
oHotzone.style.height= "10px"
oHotzone.style.width = "100%"
oHotzone.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {alert('hotzone');});
document.body.appendChild(oHotzone);

document.body.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {alert('body');});
```